# Is there a way to clear every application's cache?

Tags: sd-card, storage, cache

The biggest culprit is Google Music, but I would like to clear out all of my caches fairly quickly.

If I'm using my phone as a camera, having everything cached totally eats up my SD card's storage space, so I would like to either turn down the amount of caching for Google Maps, Google Music, and a few other apps, turn up how frequently the cache is cleared, or have some way to automatically clear the caches when I want to.

<sup>If relevant, I'm running an HTC Incredible with CM7.</sup>

Comment: [I'm wondering why is this not part of stock Android](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/248647/78530), so installing a cleaning app is not required.

Answer (score 2):

There are plenty of apps available that will do this. One that supports both manual and periodic cache cleaning:

## [1 Tap Cleaner](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.a0soft.gphone.acc.free)

> 1-Tap to clean all cache, search histories and calls log. A default cleaner is also included.
>
> Are you running out of application storage?
> You now can get more available storage space by clearing apps created cache/data files.

[image: Settings screenshot] [image: Quick access to clean options screenshot]

Answer (score 1):

you can delete the application cache directories, in /data/data but that will also remove any settings and things like that.

You can also use Clockwork recovery (if its available for that device) and "wipe data", but again, it will clear out the settings too. If the SDCard is the big concern, you can either use ADB or even Windows (when the sdcard is mounted) and delete the folders that contain the cache data that is taking up space.

Comment: There would be no side effects for deleting the cache directories? I found that they are located at /Android/data/[app]/cache. Can I just delete that cache directory without any problems?

Comment: you could probably run a "rm" command that would just delete the child "cache" directory, but I am not fluent enough to be able to tell you how.

Comment: I'm more concerned with what would happen if I just deleted them from Windows or another app. Optimally, I would like to control the caching behavior, but if I can't, I'd like to be 100% sure that just flat-out deleting the cache directories is safe.

Comment: deleting them "should" be safe. but there is really no telling if the app really uses that cache directory for much. Not all applications will use that directory. while it is the "standard" place for them to put data, they do not have to. You could test if it would be "safe", by removing your sdcard and see if the apps function correctly.

Answer (score 1):

Quick App Manager is also a good (albeit not-free) choice for bulk cache cleaning. With it you can do one-touch clearing of all application cache.

## [Quick App Manager](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.cerisierbleu.qac)

> Quick App Clean Cache becomes Quick App Manager, a complete and powerful application manager:
>
> - Cache cleaner
> - History cleaner
> - Task killer
> - App 2 SD manager (for Android 2.2 or higher)
> - Mobile traffic
> - **Plus!** A security tool helper that displays non system applications using potentially risky permissions.

[image: App screenshot] [image: app screenshot] [image: app screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

Some devices, e.g. the Galaxy S, have a cache wipe option in their recovery.  Clockworkmod Recovery has a "wipe cache partition" option as well, it should be one of the options when you first boot into it.  Some older versions might have it under "advanced".