# How to clean app caches in Android 11 and why is it not possible to delete all app caches in Android settings?

Tags: applications, cache, cleanup

In the phone's stock file browser's cleaner it shows me that apps like Soundcloud take up lots of storage space but it only offers me the option to remove the app entirely instead of deleting just the cache.

When I go to Android settings -> manage apps -> Soundcloud (App-Info) it shows me that it takes up 0.00B of disk space and the button Delete data at the bottom is disabled.

I already ran the "Junk Cleaner" of "[Phone Cleaner](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=phone.cleaner.speed.booster.cache.clean.android.master)" by "Super Cleaner Studio" to remove all apps caches but it looks like it didn't work (from the browser cleaner and from the available storage space).

- How to clean app caches in Android 11 in a way that actually works (including for the Soundcloud app and for all apps at once)?
- Why is it not a built-in feature of Android to clean all (or multi-selected) app caches at once and one needs to install apps like "Phone Cleaner" to do so?

**Edit**: I could clean the cache now. I could do so after turning off night mode / reading mode (it reduces blue light) and using the cache cleaning of Playstore when it displays that you lack disk space.

**Edit 2:** it works without turning off reading mode but only with the data management by PlayStore now, I think at that specific point in time after running off reading mode Phone Cleaner removed the caches too but not anymore. The problem is I don't know how to open the PlayStore data management, it only sometimes shows when the disk space is full in PlayStore.

I'll try if it still works with other ways to clean the cache such as Phone Cleaner and/or without turning off reading mode.

Comment: 1. See `trim-caches` command of [`pm`](https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/adb#pm) though it may remove other caches before and / or after removing the app caches. // 2. Because [Android](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/218644/218526) and [good apps](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/app-specific#internal-remove-cache) do this on their own and users usually don't need to.

Comment: How to do it without any console? Apparently Android doesn't do this on its own, neither do many large apps (and this shouldn't be necessary anyway).

Comment: Please make a screen shot of the screen you describe in your first sentence and include it in your post.

Answer (score -3):

Go to Recovery, then wipe cache.

Comment: Don't have that and I would have found that option before posting if I had.

Comment: App cache and dalvik cache are two different things.